# How can I display the values that I input using instantiation?

Tags: java, oop, instantiation, composition

How to modify the code in `else if` so that whatever I input in `if` will be displayed in the condition 2?

```
import java.util.*;

public class REPORTS
{  
       public static void main(String[]args)
   {
     int Studentid,equipid,quantity,studentid,equipid1;
     String Studentname,Studentcourse,Studentlevel,equipmentname,reservationdate,returndate;

      STUDENT stud=new STUDENT(1234,"abc","abc","abc");
      EQUIPMENT equip;
      RESERVATION reserve;

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      int x = choices();

         if(x==1)
         {             
         System.out.println("Enter Student ID:");
         Studentid=in.nextInt();
         in.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Enter Student Name:");
         Studentname=in.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Enter Student Course:");
         Studentcourse=in.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Enter Student Level:");
         Studentlevel=in.nextLine();   

         stud.setID(Studentid);
         stud.setName(Studentname);
         stud.setCourse(Studentcourse);
         stud.setLevel(Studentlevel);
         }
         else if(x==2)
         {
            stud.display();                 
         }
       }
```

I'm thinking of using a looping but I dont know how to properly loop in order for me to fetch the data that is input by the user in the `if` statement.

I changed my `if else` to `switch` and tried a `while` loop. But the program runs endlessly and instead of displaying what I input it keeps asking for student name:

```
while(x!=7)
   {
     switch(x)
     {
        case 1:
     {
        stud.getData();
        choices();    
        break;
     }
        case 2:                     
     {
        stud.display(); 
        break;
     }
   }    
}
```

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Class names should start with upper case character and camelCase

Comment: The way your code is now, you can't. Your entire run expects one single operation, show or input, and your data are local variables. Create a class, instantiate it and store the data in there. loop over your actions, so you can repeatedly add data and print.

Comment: how to use the loop properly sir?

Comment: depends on the functionality you need, I would go with a simple while(condition) loop.

Comment: ill edit my code sir please correct me

Comment: your code now runs endlessly, because you never change the value of x inside the loop. since you always keep the same value of x, you'll always end up with the same action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few starting points:

```
public static void main(String[]args)
   {
     int Studentid,equipid,quantity,studentid,equipid1;
     String Studentname, Studentcourse, Studentlevel, equipmentname, 
     reservationdate, returndate;    
      STUDENT stud=new STUDENT(1234,"abc","abc","abc");
      ...
```

Rename your STUDENT class to Student. Also, you don't need all these local variables, they just make your code harder to read.
Provide a default constructor for Student

```
    public static void main(String[]args)
       {
         Student stud=new Student(); // call the default constructor, don't enter bogus data

          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
          int x = choices();
          while (x != 7) {
          switch(x) {
            case 1:
             System.out.println("Enter Student ID:");
             stud.setID(in.nextInt());
             in.nextLine();
             System.out.println("Enter Student Name:");
             stud.setName(in.nextLine());
             System.out.println("Enter Student Course:");
             stud.setCourse(in.nextLine());
             System.out.println("Enter Student Level:");
             stud.setLevel(in.nextLine());
             break;
            case 2: stud.display(); break;
           }
          // this must be inside the loop!!
          x = choices();
       }
  }
```